# Singletons, Enums and anonymous inner classes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enums, anonymous-class, scjp

As you may know, some people are declaring singletons with an Enum of 1 instance, because the JVM guarantees that there will always be a single instance with no concurrency problems to handle...

Thus what about an Enum with multiple instances?
Can we say something like an Enum is a kind of ordered set of singletons sharing a common interface?
Why?

```
public enum EnumPriceType {

    WITH_TAXES {
        @Override
        public float getPrice(float input) {
            return input*1.20f;
        }
        public String getFormattedPrice(float input) {
            return input*1.20f + " €";
        }
        },

    WITHOUT_TAXES {
        @Override
        public float getPrice(float input) {
            return input;
        }
    },
    ;

    public abstract float getPrice(float input);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WITH_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f);
    }

}
```

In this code why this doesn't work:
WITH_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f);
What is the interest of declaring a public method if it can't be called without passing through the common interface?
I guess this is why i don't see any syntax to be able to declare an interface just for one of the instances of an Enum.

---

**Edit:**

It seems that enum instances are a special kind of anonymous classes.
Thus i understand why you can't call that method.

My question is kinda related to: **why can't an anonymous class implement an interface** (in addition to the interface it may already implement!)

I totally understand why we CANT do that:

```
Vehicle veh = new Vehicle() {
    public String getName() {
        return "toto";
    }
};
veh.getName();
```

(getName here is not an override)

Why i don't understand is why we can't do that with anonymous classes:

```
Runnable veh = new Vehicle() implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("i run!");
    }
};
veh.run();
```

Or something that would result in the same thing.
Think about it: if you do not use anonymous classes you can absolutely extend the Vehicle class and then make that subclass implement any other interfaces you want...

I'm pretty sure that if it was possible we would be able to call WITH_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f) in a typesafe way, since WITH_TAXES would not be a real EnumPriceType but it would but a subclass of EnumPriceType, with its own interface, and by calling WITH_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f) with a hardcoded WITH_TAXES, you know at compile that which EnumPriceType child you are calling.

So my question is: are there any reasons why this is not possible? Or it just haven't be done yet?

Comment: This isn't some special pattern--this is exactly how a typesafe enum pattern was intended to be used.

Comment: Bill K actually what i expect is still typesafe because i do not expect WITHOUT_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f); to be callable at compile time, and i do not expect getFormattedPrice(33f) to be callable with polymorphism either

Comment: Yes, I wasn't disagreeing with you--I was just saying that this is how enums were intended to be used--what you defined is a true OO enum.  The original pattern for it was called the "Typesafe Enum pattern" but I guess that's not an appropriate name anymore since enums once introduced into the language were all typesafe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your enum is equivalent to the following normal class (in fact, that's pretty much what the compiler turns it into):

```
public abstract class EnumPriceType {

    public static final EnumPriceType WITH_TAXES = new EnumPriceType() {
        //getPrice() {...}
        //getFormattedPrice() {...}
    };

    public static final EnumPriceType WITHOUT_TAXES = new EnumPriceType() {
        //getPrice() {...}
    };

    public abstract float getPrice(float input);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WITH_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f);
    }
}
```

The `getFormattedPrice()` method is unavailable on the abstract type, and therefore can't be called from the main method. Consider what would happen if the main method is rewritten to use a local variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumPriceType foo = EnumPriceType.WITH_TAXES;
    foo.getFormattedPrice(33f);
}
```

This doesn't compile because `getFormattedPrice()` is not available on the base class. Since the `WITH_TAXES` instance is an *anonymous* subclass of `EnumPriceType`, there's no way you can define the local variable to a type where the `getFormattedPrice()` method is visible.

As a meta observation, this is a key difference between strongly typed languages such as Java and "duck typed" languages such as Ruby. Ruby will happily invoke the `getFormattedPrice()` method if happens to be there, regardless of what type of object is held in the `foo` variable.

As another meta observation, it doesn't make much sense for different constants of the same `enum` to have different sets methods. If you can't put everything you need as abstract (or concrete) methods on the base enum type, you're probably using the wrong tool to solve the problem.

Comment: Clarification - it doesn't make sence for different constants to have different sets ^of^ methods ^than the enumerator type itself^. (They may have different sets of overrides of the enumerator methods.)

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Actually i do not expect foo.getFormattedPrice(33f); to be able to be called and clearly understand why. I would just expect the call on WITH_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f);

Comment: Andy Thomas-Cramer i found a case where it would be nice to be able too call a single method on only one of the instances of the class...

Comment: Btw if the "classic java version" of enum that Barend give above was using real subclasses instead of anonymous classes, that would be possible, so why not with enums too?

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
       public String getFormattedPrice(float input) {
        return input + " €";
    }
```

*outside* the overrides as the default implementation. (Next to the declaration of `getPrice`.) And you are good to go.

You can also have enums implement interfaces, to define what everybody needs to implement.

Comment: Andrew thanks but i already know that very well since i'm preparing for SCJP. What i want is to be able to forbid AT COMPILE TIME, to call  WITHOUT_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f); but to allow it only for WITH_TAXES.getFormattedPrice(33f);

Comment: One approach would be a hierarchy of interfaces. `Price` and `TaxedPrice extends Price`. Now you have two enum classes to match. The enums can't extend each other, but they each implement their respective interface. So you can drop in a `Price` or `TaxedPrice` when you need a general object and don't want to use the enum. (I must admit, I have a hard time seeing a use case for this, but…)

Answer (score 0):

> Thus what about an Enum with multiple instances?

There is no such thing, and your example doesn't demonstrate it. You have an Enum with multiple *values.* They are all singletons.

Comment: And? An enum value is, as you said, a singleton. A singleton is an instance. So an enum can have multiple values,instances, singletons... I still do not understand what you want to say there