# How to use fields in java enum by overriding the method?

Tags: java, enums, strategy-pattern

The task is to implement beautiful strategy design pattern with the java `enum`:

```java
public enum MyEnum {

    FIRST {
        @Override
        public String doIt() {
            return "1: " + someField; //error
        }
    },
    SECOND {
        @Override
        public String doIt() {
            return "2: " + someField; //error
        }
    };

    private String someField;

    public abstract String doIt();

}
```

but when referring to `someField` I get

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field someField.

What is wrong and is it possible to do that better?

Comment: try typing `this.someField` and see if it works, and also I think you need to initialize it with a constructor maybe.

Comment: That's very odd - I'm surprised that the override counts as a static context. Note that making the field protected removes the error, which is also odd...

Comment: @Zhuinden: That changes the error to `someField has private access in MyEnum`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it's odd. Normally classes in the same .java file can see each other's private fields but something slightly unusual is happening here. I tried both protected and just removing private and they both work.

Comment: @JonSkeet well that gives vision to what the error actually is, I personally had not known that the enum would be a subclass of the original `MyEnum` class when it provides an implementation to an abstract function, although it does make sense. This is interesting.

Comment: @TimB removing private makes it be `package` visibility which is apparently visible from subclasses too.

Comment: @Zhuinden Sub classes can see private member variables though.

Comment: I've asked the bigger question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011061/why-can-enum-implementations-not-access-private-fields-in-the-enum-class as this question is answered.

Comment: @TimB I'm pretty sure when you `extend` from a base class, then `private` is visible only from the base class, while `protected` is what is visible in the base class and all its subclasses. But if this is different in case of enums or in case of anonymous subclasses, then I am probably wrong.

Comment: So basically `FIRST` and `SECOND` can be regarded as static inner classes that override `MyEnum`? If you think that way it will explain why the compiler thinks `someField` as a static reference @JonSkeet is surprised about. And adding `this` will make it explicitly seek for the member in the base class, which changes the error to `someField has private access in MyEnum`. Am I right? P.S. And also it would explain why we can refer to enum values as `MyEnum.FIRST` in the code.

Comment: You can use `((MyEnum)this).someField` to access the `private` field as an inner class can access `private` fields only if the instance has the outer class type. But of course, `super.someField` is shorter… See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25011218/2711488)

Comment: Note that `FIRST.someField` is valid, though it's obviously not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A specialized `enum` is nothing but a subclass with inner-class semantics. If you look at the byte code after compilation, you will notice that the compiler only inserts accessor method for reading a private field but any specialized enum is compiled as its own class. You can think about your `enum` as being implemented as:

```
public abstract class MyEnum {

  private static class First extends MyEnum {

    @Override
    public String doIt() {
        return "1: " + someField; //error
    }
  }

  private static class Second extends MyEnum {

    @Override
    public String doIt() {
        return "2: " + someField; //error
    }
  }

  public static final MyEnum FIRST = new First();
  public static final MyEnum SECOND = new Second();

  private String someField;

  public abstract String doIt();
}
```

As you can see, the same compiler errors occur. Effectively, your problem does not relate to `enum`s but to their inner-class semantics.

However, you found a borderline case of the compiler guessing the intend of your code and trying to warn you that what you intend is illegal. In general, the `someField` field is visible to any specialized `enum`. However, there are two ways of accessing the `private` field from an inner class and only one is legal:

1. `private` members are not inherited. You can therefore not access a `private` field from `this` instance when it was defined in a super class.
2. For inner classes, members of outer classes are accessible even if they are `private`. This is achieved by the compiler by inserting accessor methods to the outer classes which expose the `private` fields by accessor methods. A non-`static` field can only be accessed if the inner class is non-`static`. For `enum`s, the inner classes are however always `static`.

The later condition is what the compiler complains about:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field `someField`

You are trying to access a non-`static` field from a `static` inner class. This is not possible even though the field would be technically visible because of the inner class semantics. You could instruct the compiler explicitly to access the value by reading it from the super class by for example:

```
public String doIt() {
  MyEnum thiz = this;
  return thiz.someField;
}
```

Now the compiler knows that you are trying to access a member of a visible (outer) type instead of erroneously accessing the `someField` field of the (non-static) outer class instance (which does not exist). (Similarly, you could write `super.someField` which expresses the same idea that you want to go down the inheritance chain and not access an outer instance's field.) The easier solution would however be to simply make the field `protected`. This way the compiler is happy about the inheritance visibility and compiles your original setup.

Comment: if thats the case how come:  FIRST.someValue inside doIt() method is valid even if someValue is declared as private?

Comment: Because of inner classes semantics. Private attributes or methods that are inside a class are not private to that outer class.

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms. You need to clarify this throughout.

Answer (score 6):

If you make `someField` protected instead of private or use `super.someField` instead you will be able to access it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it (in fact whoever downvoted has removed the downvote). That's really strange that super.someField works too.

Comment: +0 Why does this solution work?

Answer (score 2):

`someField` is private, remove the private modifier or move it into your abstract classes.

Answer (score 2):

Private fields are not accessible from subclasses which is exactly what you do when you implement the `MyEnum.doIt()` abstract method on a per-instance basis. Change it to `protected`, and it will work.

Comment: Am I the only one for whom it's not obvious that this will make the enum be an abstract class without an abstract identifier and creating an implementation of the abstract method will *implicitly* subclass the original enum type? It makes sense, but it's not obvious at all at first glance.

Comment: @Zhuinden that's a standard feature of Java enums and one of the things that makes them so powerful. It's not obvious but all the good Java enum tutorials/docs cover it.

Answer (score 1):

someField is a private variable when enums are static variables. You cant assign non static variable to static variable in this way.

Comment: Yeah, but why does it work when you remove the `private` modifier?

Comment: You can use non-static variables in enums, if you use a private constructor to initialize them, for example `public class MyEnum { FIRST("String"); private String myString; private MyEnum(String string) { this.string = string; }`

Comment: I do not know why would you want to restrict instantiation of the class @Zhuinden... It can be useful in singleton pattern when you want to restrict number of instances of that class... But in this case I would not agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is that when you say:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ...
    public abstract String doIt();
}
```

It implicitly needs the enum to be an `abstract` "class", as you must provide an implementation for it. Therefore, when you say

```
FIRST {
    @Override
    public String doIt() {
        return "1: " + this.someField; //error
    }
}
```

It gives an error because you are trying to access the "base class" `MyEnum`'s private field, and as it is private, it is not visible from the implicitly created anonymous subclass. As such, `protected` is visible from the subclass, therefore it fixes the problem.

There are some questions on Stack Overflow that talk about this problem, such as [Singletons, Enums and anonymous inner classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599776/singletons-enums-and-anonymous-inner-classes) or [Why can I anonymously subclass an enum but not a final class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970615/why-can-i-anonymously-subclass-an-enum-but-not-a-final-class) .

EDIT: Apparently not everything in this statement is correct, because while `this.someField` doesn't work as the field is not visible from the subclass, it *is* visible accessed as `super.someField`. This is a phenomenon I've not seen before, and will try to look into now.

Comment: Anonymous inner classes can see private fields. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011061/why-can-enum-implementations-not-access-private-fields-in-the-enum-class

Comment: The compiler tries to guess your intend. By writing `super`, you express to the compiler that you do not believe that the field was inherited such that it does not complain. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is the following:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIRST,SECOND;

    private String someField;

    public String doIt(){
        switch(this){
            case FIRST:  return "1: " + someField; break;
            case SECOND: return "2: " + someField; break;
        }
    }

}
```

This way, you still inherit `Enum` and you can use `MyEnum.values()` and other perks that come from deriving `Enum`.

Comment: yeah but you miss out on the strategy pattern, also, what happens if there are 2 dozen enums?  that's gonna be an ugly, unmaintainable switch quickly!

Comment: @ed The accepted answer uses more code per enumeration and isn't a proper enum.  It seems to me that that would be less maintainable than my solution.  Using a switch allows you to utilize fall-through and you don't need to rewrite method headers.

Comment: true, but with IDE autocompletion a lot of the boilerplate can be filled out with a right click.  I mean I agree, it is verbose, but that's the nature of Java.  Also, another "benefit" (in quotes because that's debatable) it that enums are actually compiled into objects, and not treated as primitives.  So you can do stuff like this in Java, and not many other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't implement Strategy pattern using an enumeration. All code ends up in the same unti (file).

The idea is to separate the code. Use an interface as base class and then implement each Strategy as a separate sub-class. Nice a clean.

Comment: Sometime it is better to have all things together. With enum you can see all posibility of the API at one place. But with Java 8 and clousours you can do it simply.

Comment: I would maybe use Enum for State Machines, if the states were simple, but for Strategy I would definitively go for individual classes.