# (JAVA Enums) - Anonymous class inside enum constant

Tags: java, enums, anonymous-class

**Good day!**

I have an interface which only implements one single method. I dont feel like making several class which all implement this one single method therefore I decided to use anonymous classes instead.

I use enums for certain static items, these enums have instances of my interface. However, when I try to make an anonymous class inside my enum constants my IDE (eclipse) literally tells me nothing (as if it is outside a code block).

My question is as follows: **Can I use anonymous classes inside my enum constants?**

If my text was unclear (Sorry im not english) please see the example below.

**Code example**

```
/**
 * My Interface 
 */

public interface IPotato {

    public void eatPotato();
} 

/**
* My enum class
*/
    public enum PotatoEnum {

        I_WANT_TO_EAT_POTATO(new IPotato() {
            @Override
            public void eatPotato() {
                // Cant put code here.
            } });

        private IPotato _myAnonymousClass;
        private PotatoEnum(IPotato anonymousClass){
            this._myAnonymousClass = anonymousClass;
        }

        public IPotato getPotato(){
            return _myAnonymousClass;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. You can even go as far as making the enum implement the interface

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singletons, Enums and anonymous inner classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599776/singletons-enums-and-anonymous-inner-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that, it is a perfectly valid solution.

As a recommendation, make your enum implement your interface to make the code more readable:

```
public enum PotatoEnum implements IPotato{

        I_WANT_TO_EAT_POTATO(){

            @Override
            public void eatPotato() {
                // Cant put code here.

            }},//more ENUMS ;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to that. The reason of your mistake is that you have two public identifier (enum and interface) in single file . remove public from enum and it will work

```
public interface IPotato {
    public void eatPotato();
}

enum PotatoEnum {

    I_WANT_TO_EAT_POTATO(new IPotato() {
        @Override
        public void eatPotato() {
            // Cant put code here.
        }
    });

    private IPotato _myAnonymousClass;

    private PotatoEnum(IPotato anonymousClass) {
        this._myAnonymousClass = anonymousClass;
    }

    public IPotato getPotato() {
        return _myAnonymousClass;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply yes

By doing this you are doing something like that:

```
I_WANT_TO_EAT_POTATO(An object of a virtual class that implments IPotato class);
```

same as :

```
I_WANT_TO_EAT_POTATO(Passing any parameter defined by constructor);
```

See `Enum` constants as an Inner Classes and you are passing them parameters of their construcors